# How to Update to version 1.2 of pgAdmin 4,

Tags: pgadmin-4

I have downloaded and installed the latest version 1.2 for PGAdmin but I keep getting the message "You are currently running version 1.1 of PGAdmin 4, however the current version is 1.2"

What am I missing? (I'm on Windows 10 64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

Did you uninstalled previous version before installing newer version?

If not then do so and try again.

Comment: No I don't know how to install or uninstall pgadmin. That's he problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have Windows 7, but did you try something like: navigate to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features, find pgAdmin 4 version [?], click it once, right-click, uninstall?